# Why is the font size in Safari on Mac OS so much smaller?

Tags: css, macos, safari, font-size

I have a website which uses CSS for all of its styling, and in Windows, the line-spacing and font sizes are all consistant accross Firefox, Opera, IE, Safari, Chrome.

I have just tried it under Firefox on the Mac (Snow Leopard) and whilst the fonts generally look a little more bold than on windows, the general sizing looks about the same.

However, in Safari on the Mac, all of the fonts appear so much smaller, line-spacing is much tighter also.

What is the likely cause of this? Is it a known scenario, perhaps with a nice workaround?

If you would like to check the situation, the site in question is:
http://www.marcusstarnes.co.uk

Thanks

Comment: that font size is eyestrainingly tiny (on windows)! i'd also increase the contrast on the grey, its really hard to read. usability ftw :) nice photos though :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you set font-size in `em` (a good thing - don't change that!) the font-size depends on the  browser settings / user preferences. You've probably got a smaller font set on Safari.

On the other hand, if you are in the "all browsers must look a-like, or the world will end" camp, then you shouldn't be using `em`s.

I'm unsure about the `line-height: 1` in the reset style sheet. That just seems wrong to me...

**EDIT:**
Oh wait, I just discovered `font-size:62.5%;`. Doesn't change what I said, but that is uncomfortably small for many, because you are using two thirds of the users preferred size.

Comment: Yes, I have the font-size set to 62.5% for the html element in the style sheet, but then set the font-size to 1.1em (which I believe comes out about 11px) for the body element.

I understand from reading various articles online that this approach is used quite a lot so when you then specify your font-size as 'em', it's easier to understand how large that font-size will be (1.2em = 12px, 1.6em = 16px etc.).

Comment: I don't know how these article come to that assumption. It assumes that 1em = 10px. But that's not the case. 1em is the size the user set in the browser preferences. It's probably an flawed attempt to combine a designers "need" for pixel perfection while trying to keep up the appearance of accessibility in HTML/CSS.

Comment: They are indeed making an assumption that the users browser default is set to 'medium', which I believe is 16px.
This is one of the articles I referred to: http://clagnut.com/blog/348/. Perhaps I shouldn't use this 62.5% approach.

Comment: AFAIK only IE has a font size setting of "Medium". Other browsers just let the user set the size they want.

Comment: OK, well at least I understand why it's happening now, thanks. I'll just have to figure out a better way of keeping scalable font sizes but also rendering them at a similar/sensible size under Safari on the Mac, so it looks 'fairly' consistant across each of these browsers.

Comment: Unfortunately those are conflicting requirements. You can have either the fonts scalable or (more or less) consistent across browsers, but not both.

Answer (score 2):

I know this is an older post, but I recently ran into the same issue. The only browser I was having trouble with was Safari on Mac. What I ended up doing to resolve the issue was change my reset from :

```
html { font-size: 100%; overflow-y: scroll; -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%; -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%; }
```

to

```
html { font-size: 16px; overflow-y: scroll; -webkit-text-size-adjust: 16px; -ms-text-size-adjust: 16px; }
```

This just forced the browsers to all use the "medium" font size and then scaled it from there. The only reason I am adding this is because there really wasn't an answer given. Hopefully this will help someone that comes across this.